# Is there a value using Nested entities in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, dih

I wonder, if there any value in using nested Entities in Apache Solr DIH over using join Queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is to support DELTA Query for each Entity (table/view)